# How to represent backslash

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace which is not in provided list

```
[^-\\dA-Za-zÂÃâ`~!@#$%^&*()_+=[{]}:;<,>.?/ ]
```

I want to include backslash `\` in this list, so that backslash wont be replaced.
If I give like this

```
.replaceAll("[^-\\dA-Za-zÂÃâ`~!@#$%^&*()_+=[{]}\\:;<,>.?/ ]","")
```

its not working as I expected.

```
"xyda\asff"..replaceAll("[^-\\dA-Za-zÂÃâ`~!@#$%^&*()_+=[{]}\\:;<,>.?/ ]","")
```

---

```
Expected result :: xyda\asff
Output :: xydaasff
```

I dont want to replace `\`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To code a single literal backslash in regex, you need *four* backslashes (`\\\\`) in the code (see last char):

```
[^-\\dA-Za-zÂÃâ`~!@#$%^&*()_+=[{]}:;<,>.?/ \\\\]
```

Each pair of backslashes is a single backslash in the string, and you need two of those so it is further escaped in the regex; you need to escape the escape.

---

Will we ever escape this coding eyesore in java? (trying hard for the pun there)

Comment: If you simply add this additional "pair of backslashes" at the beginning, you'll be missing the '\d' (digits). So digits would be replaced as well...

Comment: @Sambuca yikes! Guilty: I skimmed the regex :/.  Fixed now. Thx

Answer (score 4):

You need to apply *two* levels of escaping - one for the regex itself, and one for a Java string literal. That means you need *four* backslashes in a row. So:

```
replaceAll("[^-\\dA-Za-zÂÃâ`~!@#$%^&*()_+=[{]}\\:;<,>.?/\\\\ ]", "")
```

I assume the `\\d` was meant to cover any digit, rather than *actually* putting `d` in the list?

You may find it easiest to print out your pattern to the console, so you can see exactly what the regex engine sees, without Java string literal escaping being relevant. The above pattern is:

```
[^-\dA-Za-zÂÃâ`~!@#$%^&*()_+=[{]}\:;<,>.?/\\ ]
```

So the bits with backslashes are:

- `\d` (digit)
- `\:` (colon)
- `\\` (backslash)

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the slash using another slash.  So `\` becomes `\\`

For regular expressions I believe you need to escape it again...

```
.replaceAll("[^-\\dA-Za-zÂÃâ~!@#$%^&*()_+=[{]}\\:;<,>.?/ ]","")
                ^^                            ^^
```

If you need to include the `\` slash as well, you will need to escape it like `\\\\`

Answer (score 1):

To have a literal backslash in a java regex that is supplied as a string literal in code, you need FOUR backslashes.

`\\\\`

This is because you want `\\` to be in the actual regex, but the compiler also looks at \ as an escape for the string literal, so you need to escape each one again to get it through into the actual string at runtime!