# Why is `\.` not a valid escape sequence in java regex

Tags: java, regex

In the GWT tutorial where you build a [stock watcher](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/manageevents.html) there is this regex expression to check if an input is valid:

```
if (!symbol.matches("^[0-9A-Z\\.]{1,10}$"))
```

Which allows inputs *between 1 and 10 chars that are numbers, letters, or dots.*

The part that confuses me is the `\\.`

I interpret this as escaped backslash `\\` and then a `.` which stands for any character. And I thought the correct expression would be `\.` to escape the dot but doing this results in a regex error in eclipse `Invalid escape sequence`.

Am I missing the obvious here?

Comment: It's a string literal - you want a backslash in the actual string, so you need to escape that for a normal Java string literal. Ignore the regex aspect: just `String x = "\.";` isn't valid Java code.

Comment: At least related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503280/how-to-represent-backslash

Comment: Oh... OK, kind of obvious. Thanks!

Comment: You do not need to escape the dot in the character class at all. Escape it or not, it will match a literal dot. There is just no escape sequence as `\.`. And this thread is about the same issue: [`Java doesn't work with regex \s, says: invalid escape sequence`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733255/java-doesnt-work-with-regex-s-says-invalid-escape-sequence).

Comment: `\\.` is **not** an escaped backslash followed by a colon. As the others have mentioned, Java needs to escape backslash in Strings, so this is equivalent to `\.` as Regex. If you want to have an escaped backslash in Regex, you'd have to write it like this: `\\\\.` where each `\\ ` represents one backslash in the Regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of the hassles of regular expressions in Java. That `\\` is **not** an escaped backslash at the regex level, just at the string level.

This string:

```
"^[0-9A-Z\\.]{1,10}$"
```

Defines this regular expression:

```
^[0-9A-Z\.]{1,10}$
```

...because the escape is consumed by the string literal.

Answer (score 1):

`\` is the escape symbol in a Java String Literal. For instance the newline character is written as `\n`. In order to place a normal `\` in a Java string, this is done by using `\\`.

So your Java String literal (string in the code): `"^[0-9A-Z\\.]{1,10}$"` is the actual string used for the regular expression `"^[0-9A-Z\.]{1,10}$"` (with a single slash). So as you expected this is `\.` in the regular expression.